# Extract sub-string from strings based on condition with shell command line

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, grep

I have lines in `myfile` like this:

```
mount -t cifs //hostname/path/ /mount/path/ -o username='xxxx',password='xxxxx'
```

I need to extract sub-strings from this based on condition "start with `//` till next white-space including `//`".

**I can't parse with the position** as it won't be the same in all matched lines.

So far I have extracted the sub-string using grep's perl assertion, but the result does not return the `//`.

The piece of code I've used is

```
cat myfile | grep " cifs " | grep -oP "(?<=/)[^\s]*" | grep -v ^/
```

Output:

```
hostname/path/
```

Expected Output:

```
//hostname/path/
```

Is there a way to get the desired output by modifying the perl regex, perhaps some other method?

Comment: Try `sed -En '/ cifs /{s,.*(//[^[:space:]]+).*,\1,p}' file`, or `grep -oE '//[^[:space:]]+' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple bash one line solution

```
grep " cifs " myfile | sed -e "s/ /\n/g" | grep '^\/\/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using some non-PCRE based solutions like

```
sed -En '/ cifs /{s,.*(//[^[:space:]]+).*,\1,p}' file
grep -oE '//[^[:space:]]+' file
```

The `grep` solution simply extracts all occurrences of `//` and 1+ non-whitespace chars after from the `file`.

The `sed` solution finds lines containing  `cifs`  and then extracts the last occurrence of `//` and 1+ non-whitespace chars after on those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Following command should do what you ask for

`grep cifs myfile | cut -d ' ' -f 4`

or

`grep cifs myfile | nawk '{print $4}'`

or

`awk '/cifs/ { print $4 }' myfile`

or

`perl -ne "print $1 if /cifs\s+(\S+)/" myfile`